# Create a HttpClient in Xamarin Forms in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have an ASP.Net Core API that is running.

I have a Xamarin Forms solution and in the main project and I have this class:

```
public class GetSettings
{

    public static async Task<SettingResponse> GetSetting()
    {
        SettingResponse setting = new SettingResponse();

        var url = new Uri(string.Format(GetUrl.GenerateURL("GetSetting"), string.Empty));

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingResponse>(result);
        }
        else
        {
            setting = null;
        }

        return setting;
    }
}
```

In the Android and iOS project I have this two lines:

```
SettingResponse setting = new SettingResponse();

setting = await GetSettings.GetSetting();
```

In the Android project there is no problem and it works fine, but in the iOS project when getting to `new HttpClient();` nothing happens and app does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @darko . Thanx for your attnention . I dont have any key with name : NSAppTransportSecurity in my info.plist

Comment: Add the key and then give it a try.

Comment: I do that but nothing happen :-(

Comment: What is the value of your url variable? Does your GetUrl.GenerateURL("GetSetting") fetch the url? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Yes . the fetched url is : https://94720420.ngrok.io/api/Settings/GetSetting/Update exactly same as android project

Comment: HttpClient is working fine. The response you get when trying to fetch from given url is 404 [not found] so something is wrong with url. Not sure how that works in android... Show me your info.plist file.. Maybe you made a typo or something.

Comment: When you checked the url server didn't up . When it is running i tested it with chrome , postman and android and all of them was Ok . The code is in company PC . I will share it tomorrow

Comment: Hi @darko this is the new url : https://6b601622.ngrok.io/api/Settings/GetSetting/Update  . API server is running and this is postman screenshot : https://photos.app.goo.gl/jgS6EwR3N5eSKLFv8 and this is info.plist : https://photos.app.goo.gl/xcH1GcCv8bRtLjHa9

Comment: OMG . Today I turn on the PC and without any change it worked

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, next time you can try restart first:).

Comment: That's weird hahah but it happens.